# Where does winetricks store downloaded components

Tags: 11.10, wine, winetricks

When downloading an program like .NET 3.5 or any component with Winetricks, where does it store this downloaded components. My intention is to save time and copy them to other computers so I do not have to download them again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested installing 7zip and it put the installer in `~/.cache/winetricks` and the actual data in `~/.wine`

If you were migrating, I would look at recursively copying `~/.wine`

For more complex packages, you would probably want to look at `/usr/lib32/wine/` since that's where the fakedlls part resides.  I don't know that a particular winetrick drops files there, but it would seem logical.

Comment: Thanks, although in my case the fakedlls where at /usr/lib/wine.

Comment: Cool...that's probably related to me running x64 and winex86.  If you're running x86 and winex86 or x64 and winex64 the location would be different.